# Can't convert an array to IEnumerable

Tags: c#

When I hit this line of code

```
(T)Convert.ChangeType(data.Split(new char[] { '¤' }), typeof(T));
```

I get an error of *Object doesn't implement IConvertible*. `T` is an `IEnumerable<String>` and `data` is `String` typed. What can be done about it?

I've tried converting it to a bunch of different stuff explicitly before the change of type but I can't get it to work. I'm converting other stuff to `Dictionary` and native types but this particular one gives me headache.

Comment: Does that method needs to be generic?

Comment: var d = data.Split(new char[] { ',' }) as IEnumerable; //use this maybe?

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig `as IEnumerable` is redundant

Comment: @SriramSakthivel not if you want to explicitly type d as an IEnumerable and not an Array<string>

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig Note method is generic, so you can't choose your type to return. It should be `T`

Comment: How can you design a generic method when your code isn't generic? `Split` returns string array. if `T` is CustomType` how that will work?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel By the magic of *if(typeof(T) == ...)*    :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten If you're checking type in generic method then you should probably create overloads not generic method:)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Could you show a complete example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @RichardEv That is the full example showing the problem. I'm trying to design a generic method that returns different types from a serialized string. All the other types went well but I got stuck on *IEnum<String>*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you need to call `Convert.ChangeType()`?

In the following code, `theEnumerable` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
var inputString = "a,b,c";
var theEnumerable = inputString.Split(',').AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: I don't. I have a bunch of types and made a copy/paste-thingy, hehe. Your suggestion worked. Stupid brain. Wouldn't work.   :)

Answer (score 3):

Fundementally the type of an object cannot be an Interface, only a type that implements one. Since Array implements IEnumberable your string[] already is what you want it to be.

Comment: I need to cast it anyway because I'm designing a generic method to obtain values.   :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten Casting is different than Converting.

Comment: I know. As I've shown in the code, I convert **and** cast. Just casting didn't work out due to the various data types.

Answer (score 2):

```
(T)data.Split(new char[] { '¤' }).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of `String.Split` already *is* an `IEnumerable`, being a `string[]`. The following both compiles fine:

```
IEnumerable e1 = data.Split('¤');
IEnumerable<string> e2 = data.Split('¤');
```

Providing `T` is a generic type parameter, you can always do this:

```
T e = data.Split('¤') as T;
```

However, you should probably rather introduce a `where T : IEnumerable<String>` constraint to have your code really type safe.

Also note you don't have to instantiate an array to pass arguments into a `params string[]` argument.

Comment: You missed the conversion part to *(T)*. That's where the problem arises. The param list to *Split* is in fact an array. I just shortened it. Good point, though.